# How to import currency containing dollar signs on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, csv, currency, sqldatatypes

When I try to import the following data using the MySql Workbench import wizard, it reads the columns with a dollar sign as text. Manually changing the datatype from text to double doesn't work as it fails to upload any of the data.

| date | transaction_id | customer_id | product | product_code | product_color | product_price | purchase_size | purchase_price | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/29/2020 0:00 | 9900 | 1980 | fan | SKU83503 | brass | $13.99 | 2 | 27.98 | $27.98 |
| 5/1/2020 0:00 | 12315 | 2463 | fan | SKU83503 | brass | $13.99 | 2 | 27.98 | $27.98 |
| 12/12/2020 0:00 | 9890 | 1978 | fan | SKU83503 | white | $13.99 | 1 | 13.99 | $13.99 |
| 2/16/2020 0:00 | 46915 | 9383 | fan | SKU83503 | black | $13.99 | 1 | 13.99 | $13.99 |
| 12/28/2020 0:00 | 44700 | 8940 | fan | SKU83503 | brass | $13.99 | 2 | 27.98 | $27.98 |
| 12/28/2020 0:00 | 44700 | 8940 | lamp | SKU95363 | brass | $45.99 | 5 | 160.965 | $229.95 |
| 10/11/2020 0:00 | 12560 | 2512 | bed | SKU74796 | brown | $799.99 | 1 | 799.99 | $799.99 |

I tried to manually change the datatype from text to double, as the import wizard had no problem when I changed the date field from text to datetime. When I tried to do the same for the product_price and revenue columns, import wizard failed to load the data.

I also tried to cast the product_price and revenue as floats or decimals. When I had imported the purchase_price as text, I was able to use the cast function  and order the values just fine, but when I tried it with the fields containing dollar signs, it just showed all the values as 0.

I also tried following a tip I saw in a different post using the following script, but while a table was created no rows were created

```
create table t1(amount double);
load data local infile "Downloads\Lauren-s-Furniture-Store-Transaction-Table.csv" into table t1 (@m) 
set amount=replace(replace(@m,'$',''),',','');
```

Changing the formatting in excel to remove the dollar sign fixed the issue, but I know SQL is better at handling large datasets than excel so I'd like to find a solution that doesn't use excel, if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

**Stripping off the $**

How to edit data as it is being `LOAD DATA'd`.  (The online manual has other examples.)

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE ...
     (col1, ..., @price, ...)
     SET price = REPLACE(@price, '$', '');
```

`price` is the name of the column; `@price` is an arbitrarily named "user variable" that exists solely for editing during the insertion.  Can there be "thousands-separators" (commas) in large prices?  If so, the `REPLACE` expression becomes messier.

Dates are another common problem.  Here's an example of how to deal with "12/31/2021" for input, but storing into a `DATE` column:

```
        date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y')"
```

Currency should, in general, be put into a column of type `DECIMAL(m,2)`, not `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  (m=8 lets you store up to a million dollars/Euros/whatever.)

**Adding on the $**

For simply adding a *specific* currency symbol (eg, `$`) to a number that has 2 decimal places:

```
CONCAT('$', FORMAT(price, 2))
```

That will also put in 'thousands separators' (eg, `,`)

Check out "locale" for internationalization (of `$` and `,`).  Or the 3rd arg to `FORMAT`.